# Hide Span Tag of a master page from CS file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I have a span tag on my master page which i want to hide after the user logs in. i want to do this after a button click event. can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you'll firstly need to make the span server-side:

```
<span id="foo" runat="server" />
```

Then you can access it as a **HtmlGenericControl**

```
void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    HtmlGenericControl foo = this.Master.FindControl("foo");
    foo.Visible = false; 
}
```

Comment: Beat me (almost word for word) by seconds :)

Comment: @annakata - well i was weighing up answering this way, or simply saying "why not make it a label control?" :)

Comment: For the OP: Visible = false here removes the span element from the rendered output entirely which is a bit stronger and easier than applying a CSS class if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @RPM1984 - I spit on ASP controls pandering to the winform developers where perfectly well known HTML equivalenets exist :)

Comment: I didn't had to put HtmlGenericControl foo = this.Master.FindControl("foo"); is it ok?

Comment: @annakata - yes good point, this removes the control from the DOM entirely. OP, if you want to hide it temporary, but show it again later (ie on a client-side event), you could use `foo.Attributes["display"] = "none"` (i think)

Comment: @annakta - agree, but if your going to access it server-side, may as well make it a server-side control, not do things halfway. But yes, you are preaching to the converted - i'm a MVC fanboy now! :)

Comment: @Nipuna Silva - what do you mean you didnt have to? what have you done then?

Comment: void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     foo.Visible = false;    }

Comment: ok, but i thought you said the control was on the master page, but the button click was on the deriving page. in which `foo` would not exist in the current page? but sounds like you got the jist of it.

Comment: FWIW (this.Master as MyMasterClass).Foo would be stronger.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do something lik this:

```
<%if(!userOnline)%>
<span>login?</span>
<%}%>
```

In your aspx file